# If $|\det(A+zB)|=1$ for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=1$, then $A^n=O_n$.

Tags: matrices, polynomials

> Let $A,B\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AB=BA$ and $\det
> > B\neq 0$.
>
> a) If $|\det(A+zB)|=1$ for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=1$,
>   then $A^n=O_n$.
>
> b) Is the question from a) still true if $AB\neq BA$ ?

AND SOLUTION:

> Since $AB=BA$, $A,B$ are simultaneously triangularizable. Thus $P(z)=det(A+zB)=(\lambda_1+z\mu_1)\times\cdots\times(\lambda_n+z\mu_n)$ where $spectrum(A)=(\lambda_i)_i,spectrum(B)=(\mu_i)_i$. $P$ is a polynomial s.t. $|P(z)|=1$ if $|z|=1$. Thus $P$ is a monomial: $P(z)=z^n\times{d}et(B)$.
>   Conclusion: for all $i$, $\lambda_i=0$ and $A$ is nilpotent.

but i understand why : **$|P(z)|=1$ if $|z|=1$. Thus $P$ is a monomial: $P(z)=z^n\times{d}et(B)$.**

I tried : for $z=i$ then $|P(i)|=1 $ and $|P(-i)|=1$ then $1=\prod (\lambda_i^2+\mu_i^2)$ and $\prod (\lambda_i^2-\mu_i^2)=1$

Answer (score 2):

> **Lemma** Let $P$ be a polynomial:
>   $$P(z)=a_kz^k+\cdots+a_nz^n$$
>   where $0 \leq k\leq n $ and $a_ka_n\neq 0$ and assume that: $|P(e^{it})|=1$ for every real $t$, then $P=a_nX^n$

*Proof*:

we have:
$$2\pi \overline{a_k}a_n=\int_{0}^{2\pi}P(e^{it})\overline{P(e^{it})}e^{i(n-k)}d=\int_{0}^{2\pi}|P(e^{it})|^2e^{i(n-k)}dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i(n-k)}dt$$
and hence if $k<n$ we will have $a_ka_n=0$ which is absurd hence $k=n$.

Now use this lemma to prove that $P=z^n\det(B)$